# Can't see restored database - AWS SQL Server RDS Native Backup Restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, sql-server-2017

I’m stuck with Amazon RDS configuring. I’m using AWS free tire t2.micro
I’m trying to restore database from s3 bucket.

I run this query in SSMS2017 under master:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
@restore_db_name='database_name', 
@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name_and_extension';
```

As a result i see: lifecycle – created. Task created successfully.

But when I refresh my Object Explorer I can’t find the database that I restored …. Why? How can I see it and start using ? Thanks!!!

Comment: U found any solution??

Comment: Sorry I didn't (

Comment: You have to wait, it'll restore it in time.